# Pasar variables a la vista Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel-blade

les cuento estoy intentando pasar los datos de un arreglo a una vista pero no logro concretar este es el código del controlador

```
$lists = array(["name" => "Cerchas", "status" => "1"],
                            ["name" => "Ventanas", "status" => "2"]
            );
return view('batch.index', compact($lists));
```

Va el código de la vista

```
@foreach ($lists as $list)
    {{$list->status}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: que problemas tienes? o que error te marca??

Comment: Hola Enrique el compact está mal , las variables por compact se pasan así
`return view('batch.index', compact('lists'));`, tienen que tener el mismo nombre de la variable , pero tiene que ir dentro de las comillas.Saludos

Comment: Perdon no habia incorporado el mensaje que me arroja, es esteErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: lists (View:

Comment: Lo deje asi view('batch.index', compact('lists')); y me sigue saliendo el mensaje  "Trying to get property 'status' of non-object "

Comment: Nos avisas si te funciona .

Comment: No me funciona ahora me Arroja el mensaje trying to get property 'status' of non-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

al ser un arreglo y no una colección lo que estas pasando debes cambiar el método por el que accedes a el, quedando así

```
@foreach ($lists as $list)
  {{$list['status']}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Justamente eso soluciona lo que quiero mostrar en la vista, pero ¿que tendría que corregir en mi controlador para enviar una colección en lugar de una arreglo ?, Muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de responder a mis dudas

Comment: debes usar el método collect de   [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#creating-collections) , cuando haces consultas por lo regular te trae ya la collection, en el caso que quieras transformar arreglos a collection utilizas este método

Comment: Genial!, funciona muchas gracias

Comment: A la orden, Bienvenido al mundo del artesano laravel. Exitos

Comment: @EnriqueA.DíazBarrios, si esta respuesta ha solucionado tu problema, por favor [acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.